# Does leaflet allow me to control the types of roads shown?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, openstreetmap

I want to control which types of roads show from this [OSM highways list](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features#Highway) at various zoom levels.

I could not find the answer in the Leaflet docs. If you do, please link me.

edit:
Maybe i need to go one step back in the making stack and use one of these frameworks? http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks#Generating_map_images

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: If you do not want to do your own rendering (understandable) then you might want to have a look at mapbox. They serve a vector format that can be drastically styled in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to alter displayed map style in Leaflet.

Probably the fastest way to achieve your goal is:

- Create your map style in [Mabox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-studio/), where you will specify the road types to be displayed at various zoom levels. Mapbox will render the map tiles for you and expose them via URL.
- then display the tiles created in Mapbox Studio in Leaflet (or Mapbox.js which is build above leaflet) simply by altering the map tiles URL you use when you initialize leaflet.